# Laravel filtering - get the last created entry from the DB which has a specific ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

For this data (from a table called status_student):
[image: photo]

I want to do some filtering. This table is a pivot table and I want to return a record from a base table only if the **latest** created object has a specific status_id.

For example, if I filter for status_id = 1, I shouldn't get any object for those two rows.

Here's my query for filtering:

```
 $query = Student::whereHas('statusuri', function($q) use ($status) {
                    $q->orderBy('status_student.data_sfarsit', 'desc')->where('status_id', '=', $status);
                });
```

statusuri From Student:

```
public function statusuri()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'status_student')
            ->withPivot('id', 'data_inceput', 'data_sfarsit', 'document', 'status_id', 'stare_stagiu_id')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }
```

My query works, but it returns an object if I filter for a status_id of 1 and of 6 too. I only want to return an object for filtering with status_id = 6 (because that is the latest status).

I tried modifying my query like this:

```
$query = Student::whereHas('statusuri', function($q) use ($status) {
                    $q->orderBy('status_student.data_sfarsit', 'desc')->first()->where('status_id', '=', $status);
                });
```

but then it didn't work, and I think I know the reason.

first() returns an instance of another type (after an inner join, basically), which doesn't have a status_id. So I shouldn't use it this way. Also, it returns an object, not a Query Builder instance anymore.

The error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'students.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `statusuri` inner join `status_student` on `statusuri`.`id` = `status_student`.`status_id` where `students`.`id` = `status_student`.`student_id` order by `status_student`.`data_sfarsit` desc limit 1)
```

So, how can I make that query filter my **latest created** DB row with a specific status_id?

Thanks.

//Example:

For student_id = 1 as in the picture:

```
if status_id = 1:
   query returns nothing
if status_id = 6:
   query returns the student
```

Explanation:

$status_id is provided through a HTML form, and I want to return that specific student if the last status known is equal to this $status_id.

My approach was filtering with latest(id) so I get the latest entry on the first row, then getting the first entry, then doing a where clause on the status_id. But it doesn't work because first() returns an object, not a QueryBuilder anymore.

Comment: can you provide a sample of the desired output ? Also, `latest` based on what, a creation date for example ?

Comment: @ths I added an explanation.